# Radio Button clicked value get the previous clicked value React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have MUI radio buttons which I use to get filter criteria and I filter an object. Then i render the filtered object in an owl carousal to show. But when I click on a radio button it always takes the previously clicked value of the radio button. I have used ternary conditions to check but it keeps happening I couldb't figure out following is my code.
[image: radio buttons]

```
<FormControl>
  <RadioGroup
    row
    aria-labelledby="demo-row-radio-buttons-group-label"
    name="row-radio-buttons-group"
    value={movieType}
    onChange={movieTypeChange}
  >
    <FormControlLabel
      value="1"
      control={<Radio color="error" />}
      label="All"
    />
    <FormControlLabel
      value="2"
      control={<Radio color="error" />}
      label="Now Showing"
    />
    <FormControlLabel
      value="3"
      control={<Radio color="error" />}
      label="Upcoming"
    />
  </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
{filterdMovie.length > 0 ? (
          <OwlCarousel
            className="owl-theme"
            loop={movieCount}
            center={movieCount}
            margin={1}
            autoplay={true}
            dots={false}
            items={3}
            touchDrag={true}
            lazyLoad={true}
            responsive={state.responsive}
            // responsive={"0:{items:1,},600:{items:3,},1000:{items:5,}"}
            animateOut={"fadeOut"}
          >
            {filterdMovie.map((movieBannertop, idx) => {
              return (
                <div key={idx}>
                  <div className="item">
                    <div className="prs_upcom_movie_box_wrapper">
                      <div className="prs_upcom_movie_img_box">
                        <img
                          src={
                            movieBannertop.thumbnail
                            // HTMLImageElement.complete
                            //   ?
                            // `${process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL_IMAGE}/movie/${movieBannertop.id}/thumbnail.jpg`
                            // : placeholder
                          }
                          alt="movie_img"
                        />
                        <div className="prs_upcom_movie_img_overlay"></div>
                        <div className="prs_upcom_movie_img_btn_wrapper">
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              {movieBannertop.bookingOpen ? (
                                <a
                                  href
                                  onClick={() => viewMovie(movieBannertop)}
                                  style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                                >
                                  More Info
                                </a>
                              ) : null}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              {!movieBannertop.upcoming ? (
                                <a
                                  href
                                  onClick={() => viewMovie(movieBannertop)}
                                  style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                                >
                                  Now Showing
                                </a>
                              ) : (
                                <a
                                  href
                                  style={{
                                    textDecoration: "none",
                                    backgroundColor: "#2488ed",
                                  }}
                                  onClick={() => viewMovie(movieBannertop)}
                                >
                                  Coming Soon
                                </a>
                              )}
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="prs_upcom_movie_content_box">
                        <div className="prs_upcom_movie_content_box_inner">
                          <Tooltip title={movieBannertop.name}>
                            <h2>
                              <a
                                href
                                onClick={() => viewMovie(movieBannertop)}
                                style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                              >
                                {" "}
                                {movieBannertop.name.length > 10
                                  ? `${movieBannertop.name.substring(0, 10)}...`
                                  : movieBannertop.name}
                              </a>
                            </h2>
                          </Tooltip>
                          <p>{movieBannertop.genre}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="prs_upcom_movie_content_box_inner_icon">
                          {/* <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="movie_booking.html">
                            <i className="flaticon-cart-of-ecommerce"></i>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      </ul> */}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </OwlCarousel>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack
              direction="column"
              justifyContent="center"
              alignItems="center"
            >
              <img src={notFound} alt="" width="50%" />
              <h4>No Movies Found</h4>
            </Stack>
          </>
        )}


  const movieTypeChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setMovieType(e.target.value);
    const value = e.target.value;
    if (value === "1") {
      setFileredMovies(onlineMovies);
    }
    if (value === "2") {
      let shows = [];
      onlineMovies.forEach((element) => {
        if (!element.upcoming) {
          shows.push(element);
        }
      });
      setFileredMovies(shows);
      console.log(shows);
    }
    if (value === "3") {
      console.log("3");
      let shows = [];
      onlineMovies.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.upcoming) {
          shows.push(element);
        }
      });
      setFileredMovies(shows);
    }   
  };
```

Comment: can you show your button code also /

Comment: @Arjun it's radio buttons. i have updated the question

Comment: It seems your code is working fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-parm-fz0nw7?file=/demo.tsx . when i click radio the value gets changed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
const movieTypeChange = (e) => {
var shows = [];
const value = e.target.value;
if (value === "1") {
  setFileredMovies(onlineMovies);
}
if (value === "2") {
  onlineMovies.forEach((element) => {
    if (!element.upcoming) {
      shows.push(element);
    }
  });
  setFileredMovies(shows);
}
if (value === "3") {  
  onlineMovies.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.upcoming) {
      shows.push(element);
    }
  });
  setFileredMovies(shows);
}   
setMovieType(value); 
};
```

Comment: still the same outcome